# Intercepting clicks from subview in Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

My application has a custom view which contains other custom views of a different type. The subviews have their own click listeners (which I can't change, as these are in 3rd party libraries). How can I intercept a user's click at the level of my view to do some processing, and then pass the click on to the proper subview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Justin, you can play with dispatchTouchEvent() or onInterceptTouchEvent().

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but in Java what I would do is define various subview objects in my main view and simply send those to the draw/paint function.  That way I'd only have ONE click listener which would be in the view anyways.

Can you do something like that in Android?